# Lots of errors trying to install react native packages

Tags: react-native, installation, npm-install

trying to make an app for my uni project but when trying to install the navigation package I get a lot of errors and I'm unsure of what I've done wrong, going to copy and paste them below, any help is appreciated.

The line i typed to result in this was "npm install react-navigation/native"

npm ERR! code 1

npm ERR! git dep preparation failed

npm ERR! command C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js install --force --cache=C:\Users\AppData\Local\npm-cache --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run

npm ERR! > u/react-navigation/native@3.6.5 prepare

npm ERR! > yarn build

npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated set-value@2.0.0: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated mixin-deep@1.3.1: Critical bug fixed in v2.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.7: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated trim@0.0.1: Use String.prototype.trim() instead

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1:

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.1: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.0: See

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js

environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js

environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js

environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js

environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js

environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js

environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js

environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js

environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated xmldom@0.1.27: Deprecated due to CVE-2021-21366 resolved in 0.5.0

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js

environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js

environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated react-navigation-drawer@0.5.0: This package is no longer supported. Please use u/react-navigation/drawer instead. See

for usage guide

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.2: See

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic. See
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated kleur@2.0.2: Please upgrade to kleur@3 or migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax. Visit

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated sane@2.5.2: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js

environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js

environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated chokidar@1.7.0: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.0: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js

environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@8.2.6: babel-eslint is now u/babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js

environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated react-navigation-tabs@0.8.4: This package is no longer supported. Please use u/react-navigation/bottom-tabs instead. See  for usage guide

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated react-navigation-stack@0.7.0: This package is no longer supported. Please use u/react-navigation/stack instead. See  for usage guide

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated react-dom@16.3.2: This version of react-dom/server contains a minor vulnerability. Please update react-dom to 16.3.3

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated react-navigation@2.18.3: This package is no longer supported. Please use u/react-navigation/native instead. See for usage guide

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.5: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated core-js@3.0.1: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

npm ERR! 'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

npm ERR! operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1

npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache\tmp\git-clonenkarAu

npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed

npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c yarn build

npm ERR!

npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR! npm ERR! C:\Users\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-03-03T17_06_28_152Z-debug-0.log

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR! C:\Users\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-03-03T17_06_18_966Z-debug-0.log

I tried to install some navigation packages so I could develop some other pages of an app I'm trying to create however was met with alot of error codes, this is my first time using react native so I'm not too sure how to fix these so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the `@` symbol at the beginning of the package name.

Try this instead:
`npm install @react-navigation/native`

Answer (score 0):

try to install it with --force

```
npm i @react-navigation/native --force
```